# WSO2 identity server: coexistence of users in email format and non-email format

Tags: wso2-identity-server

When configuring WSO2 IS 5.0.0+ with email user name format by setting 
true in carbon.xml, old users with non-email format are able to login but it seems that the entitlement engine cannot retrieve role information properly.

Is coexistence of the two types of user name formats supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this format is support.You need to add new property  **UsernameWithEmailJavaScriptRegEx**  in **user-mgt.xml** file, which is located in  IS_HOME/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml

This property defines the JavaScript regular expression pattern when the EnableEmailUserName property is set to true in carbon.xml configuration file. If you need to support both email as a user name and normal user names, you can set this property as follows.

```
<Property name="UsernameWithEmailJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
```

please refer this [1] link for more details

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Working+with+Properties+of+Primary+User+Stores